# How to provide remote branch for the team

Tags: git, sap-web-ide

I created a new local(eg. XY) and new remote branch(eg. origin/XY) in SAP Web IDE.
Afterwards i told the team there sould click on Git Pane and create local branch by using origin/XY as source branch. But the remote Branch origin/XY did not apear for my team.
My question is, after creating a remote branch is it not automatically visible for the team?
Or what do i have to do to share the remote branch with my team?
Thank

Comment: Changes do not sync automatically, they must `git fetch` to see anything new that has appeared on `origin`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Just change your comment to answer and i will mark it as answer.